# Data format in data frame

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am importing a data base which has the date format as 192601. After importing the data I am coding the data format as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("F_Research_Data_Factors.CSV")
data  <-as.data.frame(data)
data $Date <- as.Date(as.character(data $Date), "%Y%m")
```

However is giving to me just *"NA"´s* in the hole column.

Does anyone knows what is the error?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We need the `%d` as well for the 2 digit day part as `Date` includes year, month, and day

```
as.Date(as.character(data$Date), "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried with the %d, however is still giving me the NA´s

Comment: @MiguelFranco i see that you have assigned `data $Date <-` back to the same column.  You may need to start from the original column that was not changed because once you assign, then the values are all NA and subsequent conversions are on the NA values